# How to receive socket correctly

Tags: android, sockets

I'm trying to send the pictures between two android devices, but there is a transmission problem I can't figure out. Someone tell me to revise the wile loop, but it still do not work.
When I tested my project on the device, there wasn't problem with the connection. But, as the transmission task started, the sending client was stopped and "transfer erro" msg showed up on the receiver.
Is there anyone knows what can I do to my program? Here are my two mainly parts of sending and  receiving.

I'll be very appreciative of any help. Thank you.

sending part:

```
s = new Socket("192.168.0.187", 1234); 
Log.d("Tag====================","socket ip="+s);

File file = new File("/sdcard/DCIM/Pic/img1.jpg");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file); 
din = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis)); 
dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
dout.writeUTF(String.valueOf(file.length()));  
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; 
int len = 0;  
while ((len = din.read(buffer)) != -1) {  
     dout.write(buffer, 0, len); 
     tw4.setText("8 in while dout.write(buffer, 0, len);");
     }  
dout.flush();
```

the sending part can work smoothly and no erro showed up after the while loop overed

receiving part:

```
 try {
File file = new File("/sdcard/DCIM/img1.jpg");
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream()));
bis = new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream());
Log.d("Tag====================","din="+s);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file); 
    dout = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fos));  
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  
    int len = 0;  
    while ((len = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {  
           dout.write(buffer, 0, len);  
           }  


    dout.flush();  
    dout.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    tw1.setText("transmission error");
    }});
```

About the receiving part seems even stuck at the "DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream()));" and catch the exception.

Thanks again.

Comment: Please provide the stack trace of the catched exception.

Comment: 08-26 22:49:25.950: D/OpenGLRenderer(18754): Enabling debug mode 0
08-26 22:54:00.510: D/libEGL(19098): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
08-26 22:54:00.530: D/libEGL(19098): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
08-26 22:54:00.540: D/libEGL(19098): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
08-26 22:54:00.570: D/OpenGLRenderer(19098): Enabling debug mode 0
Here is the logcat, thanks

Comment: Well, you are not logging the exception. So it is not in logcat..

Comment: I tried but it still didnt work. I post the catlog http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470975/how-to-transfer-a-pic-correctly-using-socket If you get any idea, please let me know. Thank you very very much.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing the file length with writeUTF() but you're never reading it. If you're going to close the socket after sending the image, you don't need the length: just send and then close the socket. If you do need the length, *read* it, with readUTF(), and then read exactly that many bytes from the socket to the target.

And if you need the length it would make more sense to send it with writeInt() or writeLong() than to convert the number to a string, convert that to writeUTF() format, convert that back to a string at the other end with readUTF(), and then convert that back to an int or a long. That also implies using readInt() or readLong() as appropriate, of course.

**EDIT**

For about the millionth time (wish I had a $ for each time), the canonical way to copy a stream in Java is:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

where 'count' is an int and 'buffer' is a byte array with length > 0, preferably 8192 or more. Note that you have to loop; you have to store the read() result in a variable; you have to test that variable; and you have to use it in the write() call.

Comment: So if I　only want to sent a picture and then close the socket. Do I need the while loop? Or just discard the loop and instead of os.write(buffer, 0, bis.read(buffer))?